# Update table field add by 1 every update using prepared statement in PHP

Tags: php, sql-update, prepared-statement

Here is the sample code but not working.

```
if($increment = $cxn -> prepare("UPDATE products SET `yes`=? WHERE `id`=?")) {
    $yes = 'yes + 1';
    $increment -> bind_param("is", $yes, $id);
    $increment -> execute();
    $increment -> close();
}else{
     die(mysqli_error($cxn));
}
```

Data type:
$yes -> integer
$id -> string

Problem:
It did not increment the table field. It always return '0'.

Comment: Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly does 'not working' mean? Which error are you getting where?

Comment: The value is not being incremented. Always return '0'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$yes`needs to be initialised somewhere and then you should do `$yes = $yes + 1;` or shorter `$yes +=1;` or even shorter `$yes++;`.

Comment: 'yes' is field from the table that need to be incremented. It is not a PHP variable.

Comment: Oh, I see. But you can't use binding for such variable expressions! However, since you always increment in that branch of the code, why not change the statement to `UPDATE products SET yes=yes+1  WHERE `id`=?`

Comment: 'yes' increment value may not always '1'. This can be any integer number from the user. '1' is just used for data representation.

Comment: Ok, so why not `UPDATE products SET yes=yes+? WHERE `id`=?`

Comment: oh, I was not able to see that. Thanks! I will try.

Comment: Great, glad I was able to help :-) Pls do not forget to mark thus thread as solution, so that the q no longer is shown as 'open'...